# sending json result to the mvc view

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm sending user request from mvc view to the controller and controller after some processing send result as json object back to the view.
my current solution working but I want to render html elements on the view side, not in the js  function (as it is now).

```
function GetTabData(xdata) {
    $.ajax({
        url: ('/Home/GetData'),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: xdata }),

        success: function (result) {
            var data = null;
            data = '<div class="list-products clearfix">
            data += '<a href="/Home/MyData/' + item.Id + '">
....
}
```

so I want to remove all this divs and other html elements and send pure data and format this on the view, how can I do this?

Comment: GetTabData() should accept one more argument to allow for callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, then have your controller action return a `PartialView` containing the *ready-to-be-used* HTML fragment instead of a JsonResult:

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    MyViewModel model = ...
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Now all you need to do inside your success callback is use the jQuery's [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function:

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#someContainingDiv').html(data);
}
```

you would then have a corresponding partial view (`~/Views/Home/GetData.cshtml`) that will be strongly typed to the view model and render the corresponding HTML:

```
@model MyViewModel
<div class="list-products clearfix">
@Html.ActionLink("click me", "MyData", "Home", new { id = Mode.Id }, null)
...
```

As you can see this allows you to use HTML helpers that would generate proper markup and urls, whereas in your original example you were hardcoding urls in your anchor tag like `/Home/MyData` which is really a very bad thing to do.

You should really find the balance between pure JSON data being sent from your contorller actions invoked by an AJAX requests and sending partial views containing markup. If you find yourself using lots of string concatenations in your AJAX success callbacks in order to build some HTML markup, then you should probably switch your server side logic to directly return the desired HTML.